# Exemplo simples de blockchain p2p em python, alguem tem?

Tags: python, hash, blockchain

Olá,
Estou interessado na tecnologia blockchain para rastrear procedência de produtos para evitar fraude (bebidas importadas). Alguém teria exemplos e como começar em python.

valeu.

Comment: Mas a blockchain registra só valores e carteiras. Como você faria pra saber a procedência só com essas informações?

Comment: Da pra fazer isso usando o blockchain da Ethereum que ao contrario do blockchain do bitcoin, ele possui inteligência na gestão dos dados. Através do ethereum é possível criar apps inteligentes que rastreiam transações do que vc quiser!!! .

Comment: Queria ver algo em python pra fazer isso, pq é a linguagem que melhor conheço!

Comment: EX: Em junho passado, a empresa de rastreamento de madeira, a BVRio anunciou que iria usar a ferramenta Regis, de Novy, para a construção de registos descentralizados para ajudar a rastrear a origem da madeira colhida na Amazônia e em outros lugares na região. Utilizando o Regis, que registra informações de identificação através da blockchain ethereum, a BVRio pontua cada viga de madeira com base em onde vem e quem as colheu, para ajudar a garantir a sua legalidade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Esta biblioteca](https://github.com/ricmoo/pycoind) foi escrita com um explorador de blockchains. Você pode localizar as informações pela identificação da moeda ou o hash do bloco.

Naturalmente que mais trabalho do que isso será necessário. Você possivelmente terá que desenvolver uma base de informações para associar a procedência das carteiras (confesso que não faço a menor ideia de onde você irá obter as informações de cada carteira, mas é um começo).

Comment: legal cara, já é um bom começo!!!! os dados dos produtos já estão em um DB.